# Storing variables via Ajax Post or other

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I want to store a particular variable from a Google maps click event. I'm thinking the only way is to use some type of post Ajax call. The only problem is I don't know how to integrate the form inside my event.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) 
{
    return function() 
    {
        infowindow.setContent("<a href="+SID[i].innerHTML+">" 
                              + lis[i].innerHTML+" </a?>"+"<br/>"
                              + "<a href='#' id='directions' >Get Directions </a>");

        infowindow.open(map, marker);                   
    }   
})
    (marker, i));
```

So when I click a particular marker I want to store the markers position, which will be SID[i]. Later on within the same page I will use the stored variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as the page is not reloading you can store a variable using any of the following:

- Scoped JS variable
- HTML5 local storage (persistent, will work on page refreshes as well)
- jQuery data attribute

**A scoped JS variable example**

```
(function($)
{
    var storedMarker;

    $(function()
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i)
        {
            storedMarker = marker;

            //continue with click logic
            ...
        })(marker, i));

        // Do something with stored marker
        $('.useStoredMarker').click(function(event)
        {
            if (storedMarker instanceof google.maps.Marker)
            {
                // storedMarker exists do something with it
            }
            else
            {
                // Marker doesnt exist show error or do nothing
            }
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML 5 local storage**

```
// Instead of storing variable in JS you can use this (HTML5 only)
localStorage.setItem("clickedMarker", marker);

// Retrieving it
var clickedMarker = localStorage.getItem("clickedMarker");
```

**jQuery Data attribute**

```
// Assign the marker to a DOM elements data attribute
$('#clickedMarkers').data('marker', marker);

// Retrieving it
var clickedMarker = $('#clickedMarkers').data('marker');
```

Comment: Great answer to this question. Is any particular method considered better practice?

Comment: @agconti It's a matter of preference really. jQuery is a library that needs including so can't be considered a be all end all solution, the JS variable solutions would probably be better though more verbose. HTML5 localstorage is not supported in older browsers, so again can't be trusted all the time (yet). For the moment I'd use JS local vars if I'm not using jQuery heavily in a site.